# React application published on IIS on window server 2008 R2 shows a blank page

Tags: reactjs, iis

A React application published on IIS on my PC with Windows 10 works instead on IIS on window server 2008 R2 shows a blank page.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "comande",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.7",
  "@capacitor/core": "2.4.7",
  "@ionic/react": "^5.5.0",
  "@ionic/react-router": "^5.5.0",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
  "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
  "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
  "@types/node": "^12.19.15",
  "@types/react": "^16.14.3",
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.10",
  "@types/react-router": "^5.1.11",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
  "axios": "^0.21.1",
  "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
  "ionicons": "^5.4.0",
  "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
  "react": "^17.0.1",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  "react-router": "^5.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
  "typescript": "^4.1.3",
  "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
  "workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-core": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-expiration": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-precaching": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-routing": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-strategies": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-streams": "^5.1.4"
  }
```

Comment: this didn't work for me:  If you’re using create-react-app, you won’t have to deal with Webpack configs. 
Instead – ejected or not –  
we just have to specify “homepage” in our package.json

Comment: All modern web stacks are now dropping IE support and Microsoft also sunsets IE. You won't expect anything new to work there. BTW, Windows Server 2008 R2 is already end of life. Try not to stay in the past.

Comment: Did you get any error messages? Please use F12 check if there are related error messages in your console.

Answer (score 0):

the problem occurs only on internet explorer on chrome everything ok